# Get a CSS fallback background image to load only if the main one fails

Tags: javascript, css, image, webp, fallback

I'm working on optimizing my site, so transforming the pictures to Webp. Problem is, Safari browsers don't support Webp, so I have to set a fallback image for them. In HTML it's easy enough, just using the `<picture>` element, but in CSS there's no equivalent. Right now I have just set two backgrounds, so if one doesn't work, the other one will show, like this:

```
.header {background-image: url(images/main.webp), url(images/main.jpg); }
```

Problem with that is that it will make the browser load both of the images all the time, which defeats the point of optimization. Can I make the 2nd image to load only if the first one fails? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one solution for now which is making two classes with a different image URL to fix the unsupporting browsers for webp format something like this

```
.no-webp .elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
}

.webp .elementWithBackgroundImage{
  background-image: url("image.webp");
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then how do I "activate" a class depending on the browser compatibility?

Comment: by using modernizer tool and for more details read this beautiful article on css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/